# C# консоль, подключение базы данных

Tags: c#, база-данных, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, консоль

Необходимо подключить базу данных(например SQL ACESS, но можно и другие) в консольное приложение.
Все что удалось найти в данный момент, так это подключение через форму, а там готовый компонент отвечающий за подключение "bindingSource".

Еще предлагали через <kbd>Вид</kbd>-><kbd>Другие окна</kbd>-><kbd>Источники данных</kbd>-><kbd>База данных</kbd>
Но в выборе источников базы данных нет(Visual Studio 2015)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у меня в меню инструменты существует пункт подключиться к базе данных, в котором создается подключение к необходимому источнику данных

Comment: Подключение БД из кода: https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/306636

Comment: А если понадобиться использовать БД про которую студия не в курсе? подключайтесь вручную, это не так сложно как кажется, ссылку на документацию вам уже предоставили, там есть все необходимое и ссылки на сопутствующие материалы.

Answer (score 2):

Я советую подключать базы вручную и взаимодействовать с ними через micro-ORM. SQL не на столько сложен что бы его шарахатся. А взаимодействие через micro-ORM дает достаточно удобное взаимодействие с БД что бы взаимодействовать с записями как с обьектами было удобно.

Лично я предпочитаю PetaPoco. 
https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco
. Он и достаточно прост в использовании, и имеет полностью открытый код(даже, когда ты импортишь его с нюгета -- тебе импортятся сами соурсы файлов) и сам по себе довольно быстрый.

```
   string connectionStr = @"data source=AkinatorDB.sqlite; Version=3;"
   var a = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection(connection);
   a.Open();

   _db = new PetaPoco.Database(a);
```

конектится к другим типам БД по тому же принципу.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать создание пустого проекта(.Net Framework). В обозревателе решений есть вкладка Ссылки, через которую можно добавить MySQL.data. Потом добавить класс с методом Main и всё.

Почему-то при создании консольного приложения C# отсутствует вкладка ССылки

Answer (score 0):

Вид-Обозреватель серверов. 
В появившемся окне подключиться к БД. Далее существует множество вариантов.
1. Добавление класса LINQ to SQL
2. Работа с EntityFramework
...
Это основные. Самый простой и быстрый способ начать работу с БД, это подкинуть классы LINQ. Правой кнопкой на проекте в обозревателе решения - Добавить существующий элемент - Классы LINQ to SQL (На вкладке данные). После этого добавиться dbml файл, открыв его двойным нажатием в визуальном редакторе, мы можем добавить необходимые таблицы из БД, из обозревателя серверов.